# How to download mp4 video from HTML blob: URL?

Tags: javascript, html, video, download, blob

How to download mp4 video using JavaScript from the `<video src="blob:https//domain...>` tag. Is it even possible or it blocked within web browsers? I've tried every method I found on StackOverflow, nothing works.

Sample HTML code from Gettr:

```
<video preload="auto" controlslist="nodownload" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" x5-playsinline="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="blob:https://gettr.com/75e599c0-6616-4131-9d46-40c5b43d03c0"></video>
```

How to download this using JavaScript?

Comment: I think you can only download if the blob is coming from your own server address. You cannot download external file data. If this was my problem I would see if it's possible to read the blob as a (bytes) Array. You could try using `fileReader` for that, but it won't like data coming from external domains, so then you'll need to proxy the file/blob access through PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a download link like this. It will work if it's actually a blob mp4 file link:

```
<a href="blob:https://gettr.com/75e599c0-6616-4131-9d46-40c5b43d03c0" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Not working at all. I have tried that before.

Comment: Then it's likely that file is not really a blob and you can't download it directly from that source

Answer (score 1):

If the video url comes from a `Blob` created by `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`
then it's posible to get the video by doing something like

```js
function downloadURL(url, name = null) {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = url
  a.download = name ?? ''
  a.click()
}

const video = document.querySelector(<insert-selector-here>)
const blobURL = video.currentSrc

downloadURL(blobURL, 'video.mp4')
```

But if that url comes from the `MediaSource` API then you won't be able to download it that easily since it is probably a video streaming.
Depending the way it works it could be really easy or really hard to get the video.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Comment: Doesn't work, it starts the download process but stops in the beginning with incomplete network request. If it is MediaSource is it not possible to download the content?

Comment: That's what I said.
Take as an example YouTube.
YouTube also use the `MediaSource` API to display its videos and you will see also a blob url but you wont be able to do anything with it.